# Regular Expression Match/Replace

Tags: javascript, python, regex

What would be the equivalent of this (Javascript) in python?

```
var patt = /sub(\d+)\.domain\.com\/(\d+)/
  , m    = url.match(patt)
  , url = 'http://sub' + m[1] + '.domain.com/' + m[2]
```

I'm new at Python and not quite understanding the regex system yet :(

Comment: @MikePennington ah, yes...sorry forgot to add that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much already got it

```
>>> x = re.search("sub(\d+)\.domain\.com\/(\d+)","sub123.domain.com/546").groups()
('123', '546')
>>> url = "%s blah blah %s" % x
```

Answer (score 1):

The rough equivalent of your code in Python would be

```
import re

url = 'http://sub36.domain.com/54'

patt = re.compile("sub(\d+)\.domain\.com\/(\d+)")
m = patt.search(url)
url = 'http://sub'+m.group(1)+'.domain.com/'+m.group(2)
```